# odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found, SQL state 08001

Tags: vpn, sqlanywhere

I am on windows 2012 server (PHP version 5.4.29, Apache server) and able to connect to Sybase DB which was running on windows 2008 server by using the below code. Both servers were connected via VPN

```
$odbc_conn = odbc_connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};DataBase=DBNAME;Server=SERVERNAME;CommLinks=tcpip(Host=ipaddress);','username', 'password');
```

But the above code is not able to connect to Sybase DB which was running on windows 2012 server. As it is using the same SQL Anywhere version as on the Old windows 2008 server. The only change I did in my above code is the new server name and new IP like below. Remaining DB name and credentials are the same.

```
$odbc_conn = odbc_connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};DataBase=DBNAME;Server=NEW_SERVERNAME;CommLinks=tcpip(Host=new_ipaddress);','username', 'password');
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found, SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: hey, I am using  this connection string, and working fine `$conn = odbc_connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};DataBase=DBNAME;Server=SERVERNAME;CommLinks=tcpip(Host=IPADDRESS);','USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');`